# How to programmatically return or press Done button or exit a Movie Player?

Tags: ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, exit

I have a simple view with a button. When clicked it pops up movie player (Using the MoviePlayer.framework). I want to programmatically click the Done button or some how exit the movie player and return to previous view.

I can get a handle to movie player's window but do not know how to end it. Please help me out with any pointers or tutorials.

Lalith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHH, finally, i can help with something here:

Ok, at first, when you create the player, you can assign yourself as an observer to MPMoviePlaybackDidFinishNotification. That means, when the "done" button or the movie is done playing, this notification is called out.

So you now have to assign a method to be called by the notification center.

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   addObserver:self 
   selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
   object:player];
```

Then all you need is to create the moviePlayBackDidFinish method and close the player from there. If you need more code, let us know.

Comment: Well this is not exactly how I wanted to do. But this is what worked out for me. If the movie was like 3 hours i don't want to wait so long. So simply i put the start time to 2:59 hrs so that the move quickly ends and i get the call back. I could return back.